# gensim with jython

Tags: gensim, jython-2.7

Im using Jython 2.7.1. It is working fine. I need to install gensim. Does this library works in jython?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Jython does not support gensim.

Gensim has as dependencies SciPy and NumPy. [Gensim Installation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html)

Both libraries use native C extensions, which Jython does not support. There is a project whose goal is to allow the use of C extensions in Jython - [JyNI](https://jyni.org/). As of 2015, JyNI did not adequately support NumPy. See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215271/how-to-setup-numpy-in-jython). I have not tested later versions of JyNI.